# Is it better to count n ticks or run two seperate timers

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, timer, flash-cs5

I'm making a snake game and on every tick the snake moves. because the snake is moving a whole unit on each tick the animation is jumpy. The game is on an invisable grid so the snake can only change directions at specific points.

Would it be considered better practice to have a timer that will move the snake a pixels at a time counting it with a variable, and on every n tick run the code to change direction. Or is it better to have two separate timers; one for move the snake a pixel at a time and another for changing the snakes direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you're creating a "game-loop" to update the displayList (in Actionscript) and re-draw your view. When the game gets complex, Timers and listening for ENTER_FRAME events will be constrained to the flashplayer settings for screen refresh (i.e. it's FPS) and the CPU's rendering based on what it is tasked to process.

For frame-rate independent animation, you should probably use a combination of ENTER_FRAME to track milliseconds and [GetTimer()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer%28%29) calls to more accurately (to the millisecond) call animations and normalize the experience across a variety of platforms.

Basically, listen for the ENTER_FRAME event, check the current milliseconds since the last update and if it exceeds your refresh-rate (in terms of milli's), fire off the animation/state update: check for snake collision detection with a "direction-block" - handle if true, then update the snake's movement / position / state.

Flash updates the Display List at whatever it's settings, and CPU / machine-dependent issues are. The key, I've found, is to make sure you're normalizing the speed of updates to make the experience consistent. Timer's have their usage, but can cause memory performance issues. ENTER_FRAME is synced to the main timeline / frame-rate settings.

For a dated, but interesting discussion 3 years ago, [check out this post from actionscript.org](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=172895).

Comment: very usefull info but i think you misunderstood my question. My snake moves 15px at a time which is jumpy because its a large distince for a split second. what im wanting to do is have it move 1px at a time but every 15th time check if it need to change directions since the snake is suppose to move along a grid made of 15x15 pixels. is it better to count the ticks and run moveSnake every tick and changeDirection() every 15th tick. or is it better to have 2 separate timers?

Comment: also to note on your info timer and enter_frame take up the same overhead. the difference is timer starts counting after the code in the function executes and enter_frame runs based on the time since it started. That is very useful information that i did not know so thank you.

Comment: Hope this info helps. I would recommend the former, not the latter. Managing multiple timers is fun, but at the end of the day, it doesn't re-factor well (IMO).